# Finding kth smallest element in an array using Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, search, binary-search-tree

The question is to find the "Kth" smallest element in an array.
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/kth-smallest-element/0

Now I did see the given techniques but cannot understand them properly. My first intuition after seeing the question was to create a BST from the given array and use the InOrder Traversal of the BST to find the "Kth" smallest element of the array. Here is the code of my approach.

/*

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
vector<int> v;//sorted vector
node* insert(node* root,int data){
    if(!root){
        root = new node();
        root->data = data;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data > data)
    root->left = insert(root->left , data);
    else
    root->right = insert(root->right , data);
    
    return root;
}
void inOrder(node* root){
    if(!root)
    return;
    
    inOrder(root->left);
    v.push_back(root->data);
    //cout<<root->data<<" ";
    inOrder(root->right);
}
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        node* root = NULL;
        int n,el;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>el;
            root = insert(root,el);
        }
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        inOrder(root);
        cout<<v[k-1]<<endl;
        v.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*/
Now this according to me should be O(n) in the worst case, but I am not sure. This code gives me a "TLE". Help me fix this code. This is probably the first time I got an intuition to solve a question via a BST so I would like to complete this question via this approach only.

Comment: Your code is not O(n) but O(n*2) in worst case and O(n*log n) on average. I expect the TLE occurs on data deliberately chosen to bring out the worst case behaviour. The worst case would happen with (for instance) already sorted data when your BST would degenerate into a linked list. This is a well known problem with BST. The good news is that the code appears to be correct if inefficient.

Comment: And why is it O(n^2)? Is it because every insertion is O(n) and calling it 'n' times make it O(n^2)? So the approach cannot be used?

Comment: That's it, with sorted data that is what would happen.

Comment: Typo in the comment above. Of course I meant O(n^2), i.e. quadratic time, not O(n*2).

Comment: [`nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) is O(n), you could just use that.

Comment: @cigien I did not understand what you said.

Comment: @ParthSharma BSTs are only practical if you add a rebalancing process to the algorithm to stop the tree becoming unbalanced. This is how AVL trees and red-black trees work. But these are more complex to implement than a simple BST.

Comment: @john so lets just say for the sake of it I do make the rotations and make the AVL tree, will the process's complexity decrease or is it just too inefficient and far fetched to do it this way.

Comment: @ParthSharma An AVL tree seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do. It will also be a good learning process.

Comment: @ParthSharma -- Figure out [how this works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21257423e2ff6a91).  As pointed out in a previous comment, `std::nth_element` does this already.  So investigate how that algorithm function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot solve this question with BST.

Question cleary states that **Expected Time Complexity: O(N)**.

But *insert* operation itself takes average *O(logN)*, *worst O(N)*.[LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)
You are doing insert operation *N times*. Hence,

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  cin>>el;
  root = insert(root,el);
}
```

This code fragment already took *O(NlogN)* or worst *O(N^2)*.

The [best solution](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-find-k-th-smallest-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-4ab7015d802a) is using pivot and partitioning just like quick sort.

But instead of fully sort the arrays, you discard one partition that is irrelevant, and keep partitioning recursively on one partition only.

Check the best solution link for detail info.